# bootstrap не работает карусель и dropdown

Tags: bootstrap, карусель, dropdown

Помогите плз. Не могу никак разобраться.
Имеется сайт http://new.norbi-tv.ru/
На нём никак не могу запустить карусель и дропдаут для меню в мобильном приложении

Comment: Приведите пример кода, где что не получается, как обычно делают на данном ресурсе.

Comment: Я просто не знаю где именно не получается

Comment: здесь подключаю https://pastebin.com/f9NBhi9a

Comment: здесь выводится https://pastebin.com/5j6CCqUM

Comment: @labris вот обнаружил что скрипты не подключаются но в кодах выше всё вроде хорошо http://s002.radikal.ru/i198/1704/6c/ca3eb311beb6.png

Comment: http://new.norbi-tv.ru/pro/wp-content/themes/norbi/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=4.7.3 - Бутстрап не грузится у вас, однако

Comment: @labris обнаружил что папка js не доступна. Хотя права на неё открыты 644

Comment: А вы подключите js в конце файла перед </body>, без Вордпресса, просто с CDN или из папки. На данный момент у вас все JS недоступны